# Devolver valor 0 ou 1 com checkBox (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart

(Sou novato com a linguagem)

Eu tenho um checkBox para informar se o cliente deseja receber (1) o push ou não (0).

Minha ideia é criar uma variável dynamic (para poder receber todos tipos) e depois converter true=1 e false=0 como no exemplo abaixo, porém eu recebo o seguinte erro:

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'bool'

Alguém poderia me auxiliar ou me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado?

**Classe exemplo**

```
class _TesteState extends State<Teste> {

dynamic _ativado = false;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Teste"),
  ),
  body: Center(
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Text("Enviar para o histórico?"),
        Checkbox(onChanged: (dynamic e) {
          setState(() {
            _ativado = e;
            if(_ativado = true){
              _ativado = 1;
            } 
            else {
              _ativado = 0;
            }
          });
        },
        value: _ativado,
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Obs: Ja tentei converter a variavel _ativado para toInt antes de atribuir 1 e 0 para ela, mas tambem não vai

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não colocou a linha do erro (é importante colocar quando se faz uma pergunta aqui), mas provavelmente é na seguinte:

```
value: _ativado,
```

O erro ocorre pois a property `value` espera um valor do tipo `bool`.
Isto pode ser verificado na [documentação](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Checkbox/Checkbox.html):

> @required bool value,

Quando ela está com o valor `1` ou `0`, essa propriedade não sabe como interpretar, ela está esperando `true` ou `false` e recebe um inteiro que pode representar muitos valores.

Você pode corrigir isso fazendo um [operador ternário](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opera%C3%A7%C3%A3o_tern%C3%A1ria), por exemplo:

```
value: _ativado==1?true:false,
```

Abrindo um parênteses:

- Será que você precisa de tantos `dynamics` no seu código assim?
- Que ganho você tem ao ficar trocando entre `false/true` e `0/1` na variável `_ativado`?
- Você precisa usar ela como `1/0` em outro lugar que não foi
  incluso na pergunta?
- Se sim, será que nesse lugar você não poderia em vez disso verificar se _ativado é verdadeiro ou falso?

O tipo dinâmico é para ser usado com muita cautela, e não é muito recomendado para iniciantes. Quando você delimita o tipo correto das variáveis, o compilador pode te avisar de muitos erros que você não percebeu. Esse da sua pergunta por exemplo. Você ajuda ele a te ajudar. Isso vale tanto para a variável `_ativado` quanto para a `e`.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado!!
Quanto aos parénteses... Sim, eu é uma tarefa da empres e a API espera os valores 0 e 1, então necessariamente eu tenho que devolver os mesmos...

Comment: Irei estudar melhor possiblidades para substituir o dynamic, obrigado pelas orientações